# Google Font no renderiza en Google Chrome BUG [NO ES UN TEMA DE PROTOCOLO]

Tags: css, google-chrome, ssl, chrome, google-fonts

Cambié a un webhosting gratis SSL (000webhost) y las fuentes de google no renderizan, probé un montón de cosas, el famoso código CSS para hacer un repaint del texto no funciona, tampoco el JS, probé linkear la google font sin protocolo y con https, nada.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Solo pasa en Google Chrome, en Opera y Firefox se muestra bien la google font.

Curiosidad: Cuando abro la consola apretando F12 y apreto CTRL + F5, la fuente renderiza bien, pero solo cuando abro la consola y refresco, cuando entro al sitio normalmente no muestra bien la font. Muy raro.

Esto es lo que me tira la consola:

```
The FetchEvent for "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/newscycle/v14/9Xe8dq6pQDsPyVH2D3tMQvk_vArhqVIZ0nv9q090hN8.woff2" resulted in a network error response: an "opaque" response was used for a request whose type is not no-cors

The FetchEvent for "same link" resulted in a network error response: an "opaque" response was used for a request whose type is not no-cors

The FetchEvent for "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle&subset=latin,latin-ext" resulted in a network error response: an "opaque" response was used for a request whose type is not no-cors

The FetchEvent for "same link" resulted in a network error response: an "opaque" response was used for a request whose type is not no-cors
2undefined 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: Pon el código y enlace a tu página para ver el problema

Comment: Ahí puse el código, que es importar una google font, y lo que tira la consola en esa línea. Saludos!

Comment: Nicolas, insertar una google font funciona, hay millones de sitios webs usandolas, tu tienes un problema en tu sitio web, no es un problema de las "google fonts", porque si no habria millones de usuarios con el problema. Ahi no pusiste el codigo de tu pagina. Pides ayuda pero no quieres hacer ningun esfuerzo, ¿tengo yo que hacer pruebas e investigar para ver que problema puedes estar teniendo? o tienes tu que poner tu código y darnos todas las herramientas necesarias para que te ayudemos? suerte man, adios

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, entré a chrome://serviceworker-internals/

y se resolvió el problema borrando los service workers de mi sitio, hubiese sido terrible que esto pase en production mode. Todavía no entiendo bien qué fue lo que pasó.